# The following packages are not available from current channels

Tags: python, anaconda

now, i'm using jupyter notebook.
but 'import qconfig' have module error. so i want to resolve this problem.
While looking for the solution, below sentence occur in anaconda prompt.
could you tell me how to solve this problem??

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- qconfig

Current channels:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

```
https://anaconda.org
```

and use the search bar at the top of the page.